# How to list of string can separate with commas and single quotes in apex salesforce

Tags: apex, string

```
If my list of string is in format like 'United kindom,US,EUROPE,Canda';

String result = '';
for(string str: countries){
    result = result + ',' + str; 
} 

string output = result.removeStart(',');

System.debug('Output =' + output);
```

I am expecting output like **Output = 'America','Australia','Canada','United Kingdom'**

Comment: Aside from your `String[] country` line having some syntax issues, what are you stuck on here? I can think of a better way to do what you want to do, but the code you have should produce your desired output.

Comment: Yeah, this definitely seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What is your end goal here?

Comment: I have added first line code for showing the list of string, actually that list of string is retrieving from other class 
I am looking for an output will be - 'America', 'Australia', 'Canada', 'United Kingdom'

Comment: And how is that different from what you're currently seeing? Along the same lines as Adrian's question for you, why do you need the data in that specific format? You're not going to get accurate answers unless you are clear and detailed.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for something like:

```
String [] Country = New List<String>{'America','Australia','Canada','United Kingdom'}; 
system.debug('\'' + String.join(Country,'\',\'') + '\'');
```

Comment: I've taken the liberty of formatting the code in your answer for you. For the future, you can reference [the help page on formatting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thanks, @DerekF.

Comment: throwing Error - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void join(String, String) from the type String.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson - are you sure you _declared_ `Country` an array of strings like Chris did above?

Comment: Yes, I can understand but i am looking for output should be like 'US','UK', - My input is list of string retrieving from other class, here i mentioned just for understanding purpose.

Comment: @StephenRoy, it shouldn't matter how you populate the list of strings. The second line should work on any list of strings. The error you are receiving is due to passing two strings to the join method, rather than a list of strings as the first parameter and a string as the second parameter.

Comment: @StephenRoy, to be clear... when you state that the other class is returning a list of strings... is it really a list of strings or is a string that happens to be a list of items? To echo what others have said, any details you can provide to make your question more clear would be helpful.